# Issues with category predict based on text description - Cast string to float is not supported

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, text-classification

I am trying to create a model to predict category(text) based on description(text)

I am following the approach as listed [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns?hl=en)

Using tensorflow version 2.2.0

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import feature_column
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

After reading the csv file the  output of

```
dataframe.head()
```

```
category    description
CAT_1   DES_1
CAT_1   DES_2
CAT_2   DES_3
CAT_2   DES_4
CAT_3   DES_5
```

In total there are 100+ unique categories and multiple descriptions(max len = 20 words) per category.

I add a target column

```
dataframe['target'] = dataframe['category']
```

Create the training, test &  validation data

```
train, test = train_test_split(dataframe, test_size=0.2)
train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.2)
print(len(train), 'train examples')
print(len(val), 'validation examples')
print(len(test), 'test examples')
```

Convert to a tensorflow dataset

```
# A utility method to create a tf.data dataset from a Pandas Dataframe
def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  dataframe = dataframe.copy()
  labels = dataframe.pop('target')
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), labels))
  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
  return ds
```

create the tensorflow data sets for training, validation, testing phases

```
batch_size = 10 # A small batch sized is used for demonstration purposes
train_ds = df_to_dataset(train, batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds = df_to_dataset(val, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
test_ds = df_to_dataset(test, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Create the feature_columns.

```
feature_columns = []

# indicator_columns
indicator_column_names = ['category']
cat_columns = feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('category', dataframe['category'].unique())
indicator_column = feature_column.indicator_column(cat_columns)
demo(indicator_column)
feature_columns.append(indicator_column)

# embedding columns
description_columns = feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
      'description', dataframe.description.unique())
description_columns_embedding = feature_column.embedding_column(description_columns, dimension=20)
feature_columns.append(description_columns_embedding)
```

Create the feature layer

```
feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)
```

Create the model

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_layer,
  layers.Dense(128, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01),activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(128, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.01),activation='relu'),
  layers.Dropout(.1),
  layers.Dense(1)
])
```

Compile the model

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Fit the model

```
model.fit(train_ds,validation_data=val_ds,epochs=10)
```

On running the model, get the error

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-225dd2fc0a8d> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(train_ds,validation_data=val_ds,epochs=10)

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
     [[node Cast (defined at <ipython-input-34-225dd2fc0a8d>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3353]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I am not sure where is the error in the code. Also, is this the right approach to solve the problem described earlier?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem not only with categorical features, but also numeric features. It works if I don't use any feature_columns. The issue is gone after downgrading to tensorflow 2.1